# Understanding vhost in Express Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand how `vhost` actually works in Express JS. Here's a working code sample (forgot where I pulled this from):

```
// -- inside index.js --
var EXPRESS = require('express');
var app = EXPRESS.createServer();

app.use(EXPRESS.vhost('dev.example.com', require('./dev').app));

app.listen(8080);


// -- inside dev.js --
var EXPRESS = require('express');
var app = exports.app = EXPRESS.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    // Handle request...
});
```

Now, my question is, why do we call `createServer()` twice? Why does this even work? Is `vhost` internally "merging" the two servers together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node.js is event-driven, and when a request comes in, the `request` event is raised on a `http.Server`. So basically, `express.vhost` (or really, [`connect.vhost`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html)) is a middleware function which raises the `request` event on another instance of a `http.Server`:

```
function vhost(req, res, next){
    if (!req.headers.host) return next();
    var host = req.headers.host.split(':')[0];
    if (req.subdomains = regexp.exec(host)) {
      req.subdomains = req.subdomains[0].split('.').slice(0, -1);
      server.emit('request', req, res);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
```